# Есть скрипт, который удаляет / добавляет классы, но делает это только раз, а надо чтобы повторялся

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Ситуация такая:

Есть скрипт:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev").click(function(){
            $(".time-wrapper,.burger,.logo,.owl-prev").addClass("block-off"); return false,
            $(".main-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next").addClass("come-back"); return false;
        });
    });
</script>

.come-back
  display: block !important

.block-off
  display: none
```

он добавляет / отнимает классы у блоков ( по факту скрывает и возвращает блоки ). Я нажимаю на кнопку слайдера, пропадает таймер, и два блока, появляется кнопка в другую сторону - я жму на нее - таймер и два блока вернулись. Но осуществляется это только один раз, то есть когда я еще раз жму на кнопку то блоки не пропадают, а все так и остается.

Еще одно огромное НО - как мы можем видеть класс `.come-back` имеет в себе `!important` так как без него класс попросту не работает. Вообщем нужен скрипт который будет работать так же только многократно, и даст возможность добавления `display: block` без `!important`. Заранее благодарен за все ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) или [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) (тоже самое, но с анимацией). Он скрывает блок, если он виден, и показывает, если скрыт. Дополнительные классы при этом не понадобятся.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev").click(function(){
            $(".time-wrapper,.burger,.logo,.owl-prev").toggle();
            $(".main-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next").toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Если же у вас скрывается блок по одной кнопке, а появляется по другой, нужно использовать [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) и [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$("...").hide();//скрыли один блок
$("...").show();//показали второй
```

Есть так-же функция которая показывает/убирает класс - [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Поскольку класс будет убран, то и влияние `!important` пропадет, вам не о чем беспокоиться.

```
$(".time-wrapper,.burger,.logo,.owl-prev").toggleClass("block-off"); 
$(".main-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next").toggleClass("come-back"); 
return false;
```

Comment: Классс .come-back без !important по прежнему не добавляется.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, если вы убираете класс, правило с `!important` перестает действовать

Comment: Щас еще с show и hide попробую, Господи, как же круто знать JS

Comment: ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ, СПАСИБО ВАМ, ВЫ ЛУЧШИЙ!